How can a quantum gate be constructed to evaluate a blackbox function (as in the Deutsch's algorithm)?
The standard Deutsch's algorithm uses a control-U gate, which takes the control qubit state $x$ as input to get the output from a black-box function $f(x)$. And the output modifies the quantum state of the target qubit. Since $f(x)$ is not known in advance, I'd assume it is a program in a classical computer. Then, how do we feed the quantum state $x$ into the classical computer, and how do we use the output of the classical computer to modify a quantum state?
Another scenario is the $a^x (\mod N)$ function in Shor's algorithm. How can this function be realized as a quantum gate?

You can't feed a quantum state into a classical computer. What you can do however is implement the classical operations on a quantum computer. This can always be done efficiently by simply making all classical operations invertible (eg you replace AND gates with a CCNOT etc). See eg this related question on qc.SE, as well as Implementing "Classical AND Gate" and "Classical OR Gate" with a quantum circuit and links therein.

Thanks for the stimulating answer. But I think I was stuck by the term "black-box" function, which is obviously unknown to me. I think the assumption is that it is known to some else who can implement it using a quantum circuit.

When I asked the question, I was stuck by the term "black-box function," which implies its internal working is unknown. If I'm given a black box, I'd assume it most likely has conventional circuitry and uses classical bits and bytes as input and output.
Now I understand the true implication of the term black box: Someone else knows the construct of the function $f(x)$ and can implement it using quantum gates before giving me the quantum circuit in a black box. Of course, the input and output of the circuitry are qubits. Section 4.5 of the seminal book by Nielson and Chuang shows that an arbitrary classical function may be approximated to arbitrary accuracy by a quantum circuit.

(+1) "someone else knows the construct of the function f(x)
and can implement it using quantum gates before giving me the quantum circuit in a black box"!
