Go a step further and get the both results of $f(x)$ in Deutsch algorithm
The Deutsch-Josza algorithm gives the result in one operation of the type of a $(0,1) \mapsto (0,1)$ function $f(x)$, i.e. if $f(x)$, is constant or balanced. With the parallel computing power of a quantum computer, I'd think it's possible to conclude in one quantum operation the results of function $f(x)$ — 4 possible sets: $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$, and $(1,1)$. It may need three qubits though. Is there any proof that this is possible or impossible?

What is your question?

Can you describe more precise the setup you have in mind? How is the function encoded in the quantum computer - the usual U:|x>|y> -> |x>|y+f(x)>?

Note that there is a Quantum Computing SE.

@VincentThacker What is SE?

@NorbertSchuch I have a hunch it can be done without a concrete solution. The Deutsch algorithm uses 2 qubits to conclude an 1-bit result. The 4 sets of possible results of $f(x)$ is a 2-bit information. 3 qubits should be plenty to conclude. As to how $f(x)$ can be encoded, I'd guess it relates to my earlier question - https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/821482/how-can-a-quantum-gate-be-constructed-to-evaluate-a-blackbox-function-as-in-the

You should try to play with the function encoded the way I mentioned above (using as many extra qubits as you like, then this gives you any other encoding) to get an intuition why it fails. I suspect a formal answer won't give you the insight you want.

Encoding, I assume you mean to plug in a concrete function, say $f(x)=x$ into the $C-U_f$ circuit, which is used in Deutsch's algorithm. The result is $|x> |0>$. It's known that Deutsch's algorithm cannot achieve what I ask about. If an algorithm exists, it got to be a different algorithm.

I mean that you take the $C-U_f$ circuit and try to see what other inputs allow you to do, which is different from Deutsch (which amounts to inputting |+>|->). If you want a different encoding than $C-U_f$, you will have to say which, and why it is justified. (It won't be if you can't build it from $C-U_f$.) It is easy to write down a 2-qubit encoding which will return all values of f, both quantumly and classically.

My understanding is that the first qubit of the input in Deutsch $|+>$ is for the purpose of inputting both 0 and 1 to $f(x)$. The second qubit is an ancilla and seems to be specific to the question. What is the quantum encoding of returning all values of $f(x)$?

It turns out that a quantum computer cannot speed up the determination of both $f(0)$ and $f(1)$.  The Deutsch–Jozsa algorithm algorithm only speeds up the determination of $|f(0)-f(1)|$ by one operation of $f$, by acting with $f$ on a superposition, rather than $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ separately.  To improve that to give $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ both, another application of $f$ is needed, which means that it takes the same two steps as the classical algorithm.
The proof of this fact is fairly elementary.  Note that in order to get values of both $f(0)$ and $f(1)$, two measurements need to be made, which entails making, at a minimum, two measurements of the computer's q-bits.  You might hope to evade this by measuring different q-bits [and so using the output from a measurement on one subspace to give $f(0)$ and a measurement on a different subspace to giv3e $f(1)$].  However, this is not possible, since $f$ is a binary function.  This means that the action of a unitary transformation that depends on $f$ can be split into its action on at most two subspaces, each of which can can be characterized by the measurement of a single a-bit in that subspace.  So no algorithm can do better than one with just two q-bits.

Any reference or proof of "a quantum computer cannot speed up the determination of both f(0) and f(1)?"
